# jQuery sortable when sorting ids of elements are sorted in ascending order instead of their sorted order

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I have some code to order a few elements (input fields) and would like to store the sort order in my database. Sorting works and the ids are shown in the correct order when inspecting element, but when I add a new input field all ids are updated and ordered in ascending order instead of the order I sorted them in before adding a new input.

Example:

I add three fields and have them like:

```
1
2
3
```

I drag 3 to the first place so I have:

```
3
1
2
```

But then I add a new field and the order changes to:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Instead of

```
3
1
2
4
```

This is my HTML at the moment:

```
<button id="addcategory" class="btn btn-success btn-lg waves-effect btnadd">Extra categorie</button>
<form id="lijstform">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <label class="lijstnaamtitle">Lijst naam</label>
      <label class="displaynonecoid" id="coid"><?PHP echo $getbedrijfinfo['id']; ?></label>
      <input class="form-control name_list catinput lijsttitle" type="text" name="lijsttitle">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="dynamic_field">
    <div class="row sortwrap" id="1">
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <input type="text" name="category[]" placeholder="1. Voeg een categorie toe" class="form-control name_list catinput" />
        <i class="mdi mdi-sort dragndrop"></i>
        <div class="questionlist questionwrap">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
              <button class="btn btn-success questionbutton">Extra vraag</button>
              <input type="text" name="question[]" placeholder="1. Voeg een vraag toe" class="form-control name_list questioninput" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<div class="lijstresult">

</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <button class="btn btn-success inspectiebutton lijstbutton">Opslaan</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is my jquery code to sort fields, add new fields and update the ids:

```
// HTML template for new fields
const template =
'<div class="row sortwrap">'+
'  <div class="col-md-8">'+
'    <input type="text" name="category[]" placeholder="" class="form-control name_list catinput" />'+
'    <i class="mdi mdi-sort dragndrop"></i>'+
'    <div class="questionlist questionwrap">'+
'      <div class="row">'+
'        <div class="col-md-8">'+
'          <button class="btn btn-success questionbutton">Extra vraag</button>'+
'          <input type="text" name="question[]" placeholder="1. Voeg een vraag toe" class="form-control name_list questioninput" />'+
'        </div>'+
'        <div class="col-md-4">'+
'        </div>'+
'      </div>'+
'      </div>'+
'    </div>'+
'    <div class="col-md-4"> '+
'    <button id="addcategory" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove removebutton">X</button>'+
'  </div> '+
'</div>';
const vraagTemplate =
  '<div class="row" id="question">' +
  '  <div class="col-md-8">' +
  '    <input type="text" name="question[]" class="form-control name_list questioninput" />' +
  '  </div>' +
  '  <div class="col-md-4">' +
  '    <button class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button>' +
  '  </div>' +
  '</div>';

// Count numbers and change accordingly when field is deleted
function updatePlaceholders() {
  $('#input-field-id').val($('#input-field-id').val() + 'more text');
  // Sortable code
  let df = $('#dynamic_field');
  df.find('input[name^=cat]').each(function(i) {
    $(this).attr("placeholder", i + 1 + ". Voeg een categorie toe");
  });
  df.find('.sortwrap').each(function(i) {
    $(this).attr("id", i + 1 + "-order");
  });
  df.find('.questionlist').each(function() {
    $(this).find('input[name^=qu]').each(function(i) {
      $(this).attr("placeholder", i + 1 + ". Voeg een vraag toe");
    });
  });
}
// Append question template
$('#dynamic_field').on('click', '.questionbutton', function() {
  let $ql = $(this).closest('.questionlist');
  $ql.append($(vraagTemplate));
  updatePlaceholders();
});

// Delete
$('#dynamic_field').on('click', '.btn_remove', function() {
  $(this).closest('.row').remove();
  updatePlaceholders();
});
$('#addcategory').on('click', function() {
let t = $(template)
  $('#dynamic_field').append(t);
  updatePlaceholders();
});

$(function() {
  $('#addcategory').trigger('click');
  $('#question').sortable({
    connectWith: '#question'
  });
  $('#dynamic_field').sortable({
    cancel: '.questionwrap, input',
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight"
  });
});
```

This is the id I am talking about:

```
df.find('.sortwrap').each(function(i) {
  $(this).attr("id", i + 1 + "-order");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set `id` and `placeholder` if it not exist.

```
df.find('input[name^=cat]').each(function(i) {
  if (!this.placeholder)
    $(this).attr("placeholder", i + 1 + ". Voeg een categorie toe");
});
df.find('.sortwrap').each(function(i) {
  if (!this.id)
    $(this).attr("id", i + 1 + "-order");
});
```